# 8086 microprocessor memory above 1MByte

Tags: x86-16, microprocessors

I am trying to understand how a 8086 works. I've read that 8086 can access 2^20 = 1MB of RAM. My question is, is there any mode of operation used to access memory above the first 1 MByte?

Comment: That _mode of operation_ would be called an upgrade to a next generation processor like 80x86.

Comment: Literally, the 8086 has 20 wires coming out of the chip that are used to signal which address of memory is being read or written. There is physically no way to specify higher addresses than 1MB. Bank-switched approaches like LIM/EMS were possible of course and allowed more memory to be used, but that is not the same as "memory above 1MB" and it required an external mechanism to switch the banks. The 1MB address limit is a hard limit.

Answer (score 2):

While not located "above" the first megabyte, the Expanded Memory Specification (EMS) developed around 1985 by Lotus, Intel, and Microsoft (LIM), did allow 8086/8088 as well as 80286 systems to access up to 4 (eventually 32) megabytes of additional memory installed in special LIM EMS plugin cards.

This worked by taking an unused 64K address region and splitting it into four 16K pages that could be mapped into the additional memory under program control.

More capable systems based on the 80386 and beyond where able to dispense with the need for special hardware by emulating its behavior using the processor's paging hardware.

This sort of thing fell out of favor as MS-DOS became obsolete as better operating systems simply gave programs access to more memory without all the proprietary gymnastics.

For more on this quaint effort to get around the 640K memory limit, please see the following.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanded_memory

Comment: Effectively how these things work (from what I understand) is that the pages are "swapped in" when needed. Kind of like those old computer games that came on multiple floppy disks, only it happened instantly without the user's input. The program was structured to ensure that the code being swapped out wasn't the code being executed at that time. Often you'd leave all your bank swapping routines in a "fixed" area of memory that you decided in advance to always have active. A lot of Nintendo cartridges (for example Mario 3) did this sort of things as well.